# Laravel: Polymorphic Relation -Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'likeable_id' cannot be null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, polymorphism

I'm playing around with the polymorphic relationships in Laravel. When i try to like something i get an error:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'likeable_id' cannot be
>   null - [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUMVs.png)

If i add likeable_id to null, then the likeable_id is empty: [SQL DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOAM8.png)

**Like Model**

```
   public function likeable()
    {
      return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

**Post Model**

```
public function likes()
{
   return $this->morphMany(Like::class, 'likeable');

}
```

**PostLikeController**

```
 public function store(Request $request, Place $topic, Post $post)
   {

       $like = new Like;

       $like->user()->associate($request->user());

       $post->likes()->save($like);

       return redirect()->route('web.consumer.post.index');


   }
```

**Migrations**

```
 Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('likeable_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('likeable_type');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

        });
```

Comment: If i enter the 'id" manually. Something like a count() Method works perfectly.

Comment: Not fully related to my issue but leaving here for future Googlers. If you create the model that will be "liked" at the same time as creating the like (i.e. `$post = new App\Post; $like = new \App\Like; $post->likes()->save($like)`) you will get the same error. It's because you first need to save the original object (`$post->save()`) beforehand, so that the `id` field is populated, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>This is an SQL restriction: Foreign Key references to a primary key column cannot be NULL.</strike>

Remove the Foreign Key reference and let Laravel handle the relations on its own and you can have empty relationships.

---

Sorry, I read the wrong column name in the error message.
This problem is not at all related to the relationship or the foreign key reference.

It's just that you did not specify a likeable_id in your store request, but also didn't allow that column to be null in the Schema creation.
If you create a numeric column and want that column to be optional in your models, you need to specify `->nullable()` on the Schema for that column or add a default vlaue.
i.e. use either:

```
$table->integer('likeable_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

or:

```
$table->integer('likeable_id')->unsigned()->default(0);
```

Comment: But i would like to have the post id in there. So in my example the post id.

Comment: Sorry, I completely misinterpreted the question because of a mixup in the variable names. I mistook the error message for a problem with the relationship variable which is part of the reference.
Edited my response to target the actual problem.

Comment: Hey Mastacheta, thanks for the answer. But with setting likeable->id to nullable, i still dont get the post id into the database. likeable_id should be in my case the post_id.

Comment: Can you update your example to show how you're trying to associate the post with the like model?
In your example, there's only an association between like and user.

Comment: But it's alrdy there? public function likes()
{
   return $this->morphMany(Like::class, 'likeable');

}

Comment: Try setting the post association directly on the like when saving instead of setting the like association on the post. (`$post->likes()->save($like);` and turn that into `$like->post = $post;` and `$like->save();`) The other way around only works in theory, I guess. There's several similar things that aren't accurately documented when it comes to relations.

Comment: In order to set the like association on the post, the like must first be created and saved. That happens before the association is then set. Not sure if your current code works at all, but you'd definitely need to save twice (once more after setting the relation)

Answer (score 0):

I have face same problem. The 'field name' in view page and the column name of database was indifferent. My problem was:
     `"Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'MoneyMethod' cannot be null"`. 
My view page input tag:`{!! Form::select("MoneyMethod", $MoneymethodInfo, null,["class"=>"form-control MoneyMethod required","id"=>"MoneyMethod"]) !!}`, notice the spelling of 'MoneyMethod' in my database table `$table->string('MoneyMethod', 100);` the spelling of money method is same as view page but in my controller `$riskfund->Moneymethod  = Input::get('Moneymethod');` look carefully the spelling of 'Moneymethod' differs from view page and database tabel column. After correcting the spelling, it is working now.

Comment: So check the spelling of 'likeable_id' in your controller, is it correct or wrong?